# Shorten object path name in Access

Tags: ms-access, object, syntax

I've been looking for a while but have a feeling I don't know the proper way to search what I'm looking for.
So, I have this code:

```
Private Sub AB1_dMnmsSfHrbr_Click()
    If Forms!frmab1!AB1_dMnmsSfHrbr.Value = -1 Then
        Forms!frmab1!AB2a_expTrtmnt.Enabled = True
        Forms!frmab1!AB5a_invPrice.Enabled = False
    ElseIf Forms!frmab1!AB1_dMnmsSfHrbr.Value = 0 Then
        Forms!frmab1!AB2a_expTrtmnt.Enabled = False
        Forms!frmab1!AB5a_invPrice.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to be able to shorten Forms!frmab1 to something shorter like "FAB1" so that I can type my likes like:

```
FAB1!AB2a_exptrtmnt.enabled = true
```

How do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create a local variable or use the [`with`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) statement

Local Variable:

```
Private Sub AB1_dMnmsSfHrbr_Click()

    Dim FAB1 as Form
    Set FAB1 = Forms!frmab1

    If FAB1!AB1_dMnmsSfHrbr.Value = -1 Then
        FAB1!AB2a_expTrtmnt.Enabled = True
        FAB1!AB5a_invPrice.Enabled = False
    ElseIf FAB1!AB1_dMnmsSfHrbr.Value = 0 Then
        FAB1!AB2a_expTrtmnt.Enabled = False
        FAB1!AB5a_invPrice.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

With Statement:

```
Private Sub AB1_dMnmsSfHrbr_Click()

    With Forms!frmab1

        If !AB1_dMnmsSfHrbr.Value = -1 Then
            !AB2a_expTrtmnt.Enabled = True
            !AB5a_invPrice.Enabled = False
        ElseIf !AB1_dMnmsSfHrbr.Value = 0 Then
            !AB2a_expTrtmnt.Enabled = False
            !AB5a_invPrice.Enabled = True
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```